# Как в google таблице можно при записи данных в ячейку сразу перенести на другой лист в ячейку?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-docs, формулы

Как в google таблице можно при записи данных в ячейку сразу перенести на другой лист в ячейку?
Пример есть два листа 1 машины, 2 продажи.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы когда я ввожу данные в столбец "марка" в листе "машины" оно сразу же переносило название марки в лист продажи в столбец "название"

А потом когда я внесу в столбец "цена", листа машины, цену автомобиля, оно перенесло цену в лист продажи в столбец "Осталось оплатить".

И есть какой нибудь туториал на эту тему, я читал про IMPORTRANGE, но не знаю он подходит для этой задачи или нет.

Comment: Перенос - копирование данных или все-таки перенос? Копирование: прямая ссылка на ячейку =другой_лист!A1. Без примера данных больше предложить нечего...

Comment: ну мне нужно скопировать данные на другой лист

Comment: @Valery ostap Чем конкретнее Вы опишете требуемое действие, тем быстрее получите адекватный ответ. Копировать данные можно разными способами: и прямой ссылкой на ячейку, и в ходе обработки onEdit, и по триггеру времени, и с использованием разных функций. Но выбор средства существенно зависит от конкретных целей и ситуаций... А они не указаны.